# Error upgrading Exchange 2013 - Setup can't use the domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2013

When I try to run the setup for my upgrade on my Mail Server, I get an error.

"Setup can't use the domain controller 'Default-First-Site-Name' because it belongs to Active Directory Site ''"

I also ran the setup with the /DomainController: switch and I get the same error.  I am at my wits end.  Google is not helping me here.  My configuration is 2 servers, one is my DC and DNS server and the other is my Mail Server.  Please post if you need more information, or if you have any ideas.

I feel like I have some sort of a DNS issue maybe?

I am on Windows Server 2008 R2

Thank you!

Comment: I'd love to see the setup log file (sanitized, of course).

Comment: Thank you, I will post the setup log in the AM when I am back at the server.

Comment: I got same issue. But I got fixed after I check the LAN card settings.